# How to access tags (get values like text of tags) inside a tag? How to get value of h1 tag inside a (paragraph) p tag?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am working with Selenium with Python to solve a problem. I want to extract information inside a paragraph (p tag). I am using "find_elements_by_tag_name" to locate all the **p** tags in the page. But how can I access some tags that are already inside that paragraph. For example there is html file which ahs a code like

```
<p> This is a paragraph <h1> but this is a h1 tag </h1></p>
```

I have used selenium to open the page like

```
br=webdriver.Chrome()
br.get('file:///C:/Users/Shady/Desktop/New%20Text%20Document.html')
```

I am able to access the elements of the the **P** tag by

```
p_tags=br.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
```

It shows only one element and when I do

```
print(x[0].text)
```

it shows only

```
This is a paragraph
```

How can I access the **h1** tag inside the p tag. Can X_path would work? if Yes, Can you please share the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<h1>` tag is actually a descendent of the `<p>` tag. So in your code trials you have identified the `<p>` tag and extracted the text which correctely gave **This is a paragraph**.

So to extract the text **but this is a h1 tag** you have to reach to the descendent `<h1>` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p>h1").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p/h1").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please just explain it too?

Comment: @Mahesh Added more details. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: can you take a look at this one too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56686492/replacing-the-values-in-a-string-for-something-like-p-anything-inside-it-to?noredirect=1#comment99939144_56686492